# Game Center: seperate leaderboard for iPhone/iPad in universal app

Tags: iphone, ipad, game-center

Is it possible to have a separate game center leaderboard for iPad and iPhone in a universal application?

The game center app on iPhone should exclusively show the scores achieved on the iPhone. When viewed on iPad it should only show the iPad scores.

Comment: Can't you just determine the device with code and then select the correct leaderboard programmatically? They would both show up in the Game Center app though...

Comment: @Jongsma yes, i thought about that. If it's not possible I'll create 2 leaderboards and show the one on iPhone and the other on iPad.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Create 2 separate leaderboards in iTunes Connect, then when you post your score, check if the device is an iPhone or iPad

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
//iPad
} else {
//it's an iPhone 
}
```

and assign the appropriate identifier.

That code should compile (but I might've made a typo somewhere)